# Python: How to differ these two functions with each other

Tags: python, function

```
def a():
    """ Need to write something here."""

def test1():
    return a()

def test2(x):
    return x
```

I would like to do this in python interpreter:

```
test1()

test2(a())
```

So what I need to do is that I write a() to make these two functions (test1(), test2(x)) return different result.

For example, I want test1 to return number 1 and test2 return other things except number 1.

Comment: differ to each other in what way?

Comment: Huh? Not really clear, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Differ? Do anything to the value and it'll be different, you will need to be far more specific.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like test1() and test2(a()) to return?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty Maybe, but it's really hard to tell what is being asked here ..

Comment: OP wants the same function to return a different value depending on where it is called (without passing additional parameters obvioulsy), I think... isn't this right OP?

Answer (score 2):

```
import inspect

def a():
    s = inspect.stack()
    if s[1][3] == '<module>':
        return "From test2"
    else:
        return "Not from test2"
```

Comment: Uhhh... What exactly is this doing?

Comment: yea i don't understand either

Comment: It looks whether `a()` is called from module-level or not. However, not very nice *imho*.

Comment: but it does what the OP is asking for ... but yeah its kinda gross